# Using IPs in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to create a system (well it's a project) where I can log users IP addresses when they do certain activities. After some research, I've found that ip2long is needed to convert into the database. I've got a database called ips (unsigned) and the main columns are ip and count.

**Mysql Screenshot**:

[image]

This is what I've got currently:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = ip2long($ip);

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO ips (ip, count) VALUES  (:addr, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1");
$stmt->bindparam(":addr", $ip);
$stmt->execute();
```

This works fine. But I can't seem to be able to retrieve the values from the database and display them. I'm probably doing this horribly wrong but have no idea. After this statement, I then need to convert longtoip. I'd appreciate some help as this just gives me an Error 500:

```
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT ip , count FROM ips WHERE 1")
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Your error 500 can come from an error on DB level. Can you add `$stmt->errorInfo()` after `execute` to know what append ? But I think it's because `count` is a MySQL keyword and needs to be escaped : `SELECT ip, \`count\` ...`.

Comment: "1" is not a condition. What are you trying to query?

Comment: and "count" is a reserved work (it's a function), but you're calling it without any arguments

Comment: Trying to query all IP addresses and counts of them.

Comment: What about ipv6?  This is  something you need to consider as IPv6 is becoming more heavily used.  ip2long only supports IPv4.  For logging purposes, I don't see the point of IP conversion, just store it as a string.

Comment: I'd like to be able to compare the IPV4(/6) string against an active users IP, is that possible?

Comment: @JonathanW why wouldn't it be?  If you convert it to an integer, it won't be possible for IPv6 as IPv6 is 128-bit.

Comment: @Devon Would you mind giving me an example please? I assume I'd get the IP like I've done above, ip2long it and store it. For future IPs that need to be compared I could just ip2long them and compare by selecting it normally?

Comment: @JonathanW I don't know what example I could give you... Your example above converts an IP from string form to integer form.  This isn't possible with IPv6 because the maximum size of an integer in MySQL and PHP is 64-bit.   Just don't convert the IP and store it as a string. Unless you truly need it in a different format, you're just creating more work for yourself.

Comment: @Devon, I'm likely doing something wrong but just putting the remote_addr in the database just gives me the first six numbers and nothing else?

Comment: Is it a varchar?  Is the length long enough?  You want 45 characters to support all IPv6 strings.

Comment: @Devon No, it's a integer. I don't believe I can change it to a varchar as I want to keep the ability to count the number of times each IP is entered through the query above. Unless you know of a way? Even with a longer int it only does the first six.

Comment: @JonathanW, I think you need to research a bit better on what you are doing.  No offense, but the questions seem like you don't really know what your code and queries are doing.  Nothing in the code above depends on an integer column for ip if you remove the ip2long call.

Comment: @Devon Well thanks for your help..

Comment: To all commenters about `count` - Let's lose the misconception about it being a (reserved) MySQL keyword. RTM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the following query, as you can see from the SQL Fiddle link given below the query:

```
SELECT ip, count FROM ips WHERE 1
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8a799b/2)

However, if you really did intend to use `COUNT` as a function, then your query needs a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT ip, COUNT(*) AS ipCount
FROM ips
GROUP BY ip
```

As general good practice, you might want to avoid naming your columns `count`, or after any other MySQL function, because it could lead to confusion about what your query is actually doing (and you may have fallen prey to this yourself).

Comment: *"COUNT is a reserved keyword in MySQL"* - It isn't. FYI: The manual states https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html - *"Names of built-in functions are permitted as identifiers but may require care to be used as such. For example, COUNT is acceptable as a column name. However, by default, no whitespace is permitted in function invocations between the function name and the following “(” character. "*

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are correct, I did not realize this.  I checked myself in a Fiddle and indeed `count` is a legitimate column name, even unescaped.  The `500` error the OP was getting led me down this path for an explanation, when it seems that some _other_ problem was causing it.  I will leave my discussion of using `COUNT` as a function with `GROUP BY` unchanged, because I believe this to be correct.

Comment: No problemo Tim ;-)